# Prove that $\lambda _{n}(A)\lambda _{m}(B)=\lambda _{n+m}(A\times B)$ for lebesgue measurable sets A,B

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

suppose that A,B are lebesgue measurable sets and A is n-dimensional lebesgue measurable set and B is m-dimensional lebesgue measurable set, I want to show that $A\times B$ is (m+n)-dimensional measurable and $\lambda _{n}(A)\lambda _{m}(B)=\lambda _{n+m}(A\times B)$, here $\lambda _{m}$ represent the m-dimensional lebesgue measure. I don't know what should I do, can anyone help me? thank you in advance

Comment: You may try to use indicator functions and Fubini's theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $B_d$ denote the Borel sigma algebra on $\mathbb{R}^d$. We have the measure space $(\mathbb{R}^d, B_d, \lambda_d)$. Form the completion $(\mathbb{R}^d, \overline{B_d}, \overline{\lambda_d})$, where
$$\overline{B_d} = \{E \cup S \colon E \in B_d, S \subset N \in B_d, \lambda_d(N) = 0\}.$$
$L_d = \overline{B_d}$ is the Lebesgue sigma algebra on $\mathbb{R}^d$, and for $E, S$ as above, $\overline{\lambda_d}(E \cup S) := \lambda_d(E)$. You want to prove that if $A \in L_n, B \in L_m$, then
\begin{equation}
\overline{\lambda_{n + m}}(A \times B) = \overline{\lambda_n}(A)\overline{\lambda_m}(B). \hspace{40pt} (1)
\end{equation}

The main step is to show that the product measure space $(\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^m, B_n \otimes B_m, \lambda_n \times \lambda_m)$ equals the measure space $(\mathbb{R}^{n + m}, B_{n + m}, \lambda_{n + m})$. The equality (strictly speaking not an equality) $\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^m = \mathbb{R}^{n + m}$ is trivial. The equality $B_n \otimes B_m = B_{n + m}$ is a consequence of the elementary result that if $X$ and $Y$ are second countable topological spaces, then $B_X \otimes B_Y = B_{X \times Y}$. The equality $\lambda_n \times \lambda_m = \lambda_{n + m}$ is a consequence of Caratheodory's theorem since both sides agree on sets of the form $I_1 \times \dots \times I_{n + m}$, where each $I_j$ is an interval in $\mathbb{R}$.

From here, proving (1) is an easy exercise in using the definitions. You just write $A = E_1 \cup S_1$, $B = E_2 \cup S_2$ as in the definitions of $L_n$ and $L_m$, expand out $A \times B$, and you will see that $A \times B \in L_{n + m}$ with $\overline{\lambda_{n + m}}(A \times B) = \lambda_n(E_1)\lambda_m(E_2)$.

Extra: The above argument shows that $L_n \otimes L_m \subset \overline{B_n \otimes B_m}$. Taking the completion of both sides with respect to Lebesgue measure gives $\overline{L_n \otimes L_m} \subset \overline{B_n \otimes B_m}$. The reverse inclusion $\overline{B_n \otimes B_m} \subset \overline{L_n \otimes L_m}$ follows from the inclusion $B_n \otimes B_m \subset L_n \otimes L_m$. Thus we have equality $\overline{L_n \otimes L_m} = \overline{B_n \otimes B_m} = \overline{B_{n + m}} = L_{n + m}$. So we have the equality of measure spaces $(\mathbb{R}^{n + m}, \overline{L_n \otimes L_m}, \overline{\overline{\lambda_n} \times \overline{\lambda_m}}) = (\mathbb{R}^{n + m}, L_{n + m}, \overline{\lambda_{n + m}})$.